# Separating one variable to 4

Tags: php, xml

I am calling nodes from XML `<observation_time>2014-02-19T22:56:00Z</observation_time>` with a line that looks like `$lasobs_time=$lasxml->data->METAR->observation_time;`. That line of code works like a champ, and I am able to INSERT INTO my database just fine.

I am wondering if there is a way to turn the observation_time: 2014-02-19T22:56:00Z in to more than 4 fields/variables I would be able to work with a little better; Maybe $obsyear: 2014 $obsmonth: 02 $obsday: 19 $obstime: 2256 UTC.

Would `explode` be the best option? How would I go about it?

Comment: using\manipulating\storing the whole date is usually much preferred, what cant you do with the whole date that requires splitting it up

Comment: It's always a good pratice to store date they way you are doing and not to split, you can always manipulate them

Comment: The function [strptime](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.strptime.php) might be able to help. It returns an array and takes a string as a parameter

Comment: I have nothing against continuing to store it this way, much easier. Just trying to figure out how to call data from the DB and work with it easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`date_parse_from_format()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse-from-format.php) should do the trick.

```
$date     = date_parse_from_format("Y-m-d\TH:i:sT", $lasxml->data->METAR->observation_time);
$obsyear  = $date["year"];
$obsmonth = $date["month"];
$obsday   = $date["day"];
$obstime  = "$date[hour]$date[minute]";
```

Comment: Awesome, that looks like it will do the trick. Thank you miken32.